# `Invalid blockhash` error while deploying smart contract

Tags: solana, chainlink

I am trying to deploy the demo smart contract on solana for chainlink price feed but getting an error. I followed all the steps from https://docs.chain.link/docs/solana/using-data-feeds-solana/

```
$ anchor deploy --provider.wallet ./id.json --provider.cluster devnet

Deploying workspace: https://api.devnet.solana.com
Upgrade authority: ./id.json
Deploying program "chainlink_solana_demo"...
Program path: /home/test/solana-starter-kit/target/deploy/chainlink_solana_demo.so...
=============================================================================
Recover the intermediate account's ephemeral keypair file with
`solana-keygen recover` and the following 12-word seed phrase:
=============================================================================
until reason almost can clean wish trend buffalo future auto artefact balcony
=============================================================================
To resume a deploy, pass the recovered keypair as the
[BUFFER_SIGNER] to `solana program deploy` or `solana write-buffer'.
Or to recover the account's lamports, pass it as the
[BUFFER_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS] argument to `solana program close`.
=============================================================================
Error: Custom: Invalid blockhash
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.
```

Comment: Hey, you have a private key there. Try editing and removing

Comment: @JacobCreech Its for devnet so no issues.

Comment: Welcome and enjoy SO. Adding system context (os, nvm, etc.) and making a specific question helps in getting a good answer. Maybe you want to edit and provide more details.

Comment: Can you make this an issue on the solana starter kit? https://github.com/smartcontractkit/solana-starter-kit

Comment: @PatrickCollins Created an issue: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/solana-starter-kit/issues/8

Answer (score 0):

This is just a timeout error message. It happens from time to time depending on the network availability

Follow these steps and run again. I've also found that you'll want quite a bit more sol in your wallet than you think you need.

```
To resume a deploy, pass the recovered keypair as the
[BUFFER_SIGNER] to `solana program deploy` or `solana write-buffer'.
Or to recover the account's lamports, pass it as the
[BUFFER_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS] argument to `solana program close`.
```